# SQL query to insert sinlge row from one table into multiple rows in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table 
table_1:

```
PID DIV1 DES1 DIV2 DES2 DIV3 DES3  DIV4  DES4 DIV5  DES5
1    D1   DS1 D2  DS2    D3   DS3  null  null D5    null
```

output

table_2:

```
TID PID DIV DES
001  1   D1  DS1
002  1   D2  DS2
003  1   D3  DS3
004  1   D5  null
```

I need to right an insert statement to insert from table_1 to table_2.  If table has null values on both DIV and DES then i should not insert those fields.

Thank you

Comment: That is unreadable. Can you re-format your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use

```
WITH a(PID, DIV, DES, NO) as (
    SELECT PID, DIV1, DES1, 1 FROM table_1 WHERE DIV1 IS NOT NULL OR DES1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PID, DIV2, DES2, 2 FROM table_1 WHERE DIV2 IS NOT NULL OR DES2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PID, DIV3, DES3, 3 FROM table_1 WHERE DIV3 IS NOT NULL OR DES3 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PID, DIV4, DES4, 4 FROM table_1 WHERE DIV4 IS NOT NULL OR DES4 IS NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO table_2(TID, PID, DIV, DES)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by PID, NO), PID, DIV, DES FROM a
```

In MySQL, you would change this to

```
INSERT INTO table_2(TID, PID, DIV, DES)
SELECT @i := @i + 1, PID, DIV, DES
  FROM (
    SELECT PID, DIV1 as DIV, DES1 as DES, 1 as NO FROM table_1 WHERE DIV1 IS NOT NULL OR DES1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PID, DIV2, DES2, 2 FROM table_1 WHERE DIV2 IS NOT NULL OR DES2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PID, DIV3, DES3, 3 FROM table_1 WHERE DIV3 IS NOT NULL OR DES3 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PID, DIV4, DES4, 4 FROM table_1 WHERE DIV4 IS NOT NULL OR DES4 IS NOT NULL
   ) AS a,
   (select @i := 0) AS temp
order by PID, NO
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, I am getting following error Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WITH a(PID, DIV, DES, NO) as (     SELECT PID, DIV1, DES1, 1 FROM table_1 WHERE ' at line 1 0.031 sec

Comment: As this was tagged [sql-server-2008], I used syntax for that. I now added the MYSQL syntax.